# Token Restrictions Helping me Understand Blockchain Logic

Tags: solidity, tokens, security

To execute the `transfer` or `transferFrom` ERC-20 token functions in a Solidity contract, ie:

```
// moves token from contract to personal address
        ERC20Token.transfer(msg.sender, tokenamount);
// moves token from personal account to contract 
        ERC20Token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), tokenamount);
```

I must first execute the `approve` function in javascript outside solidity, like this:

```
  contract = w3.eth.contract(address=contract_address, abi=contract_abi['abi'])
  nonce = w3.eth.getTransactionCount(wallet_address)
  txn_dict = contract.functions.approve(contract_address, amount).buildTransaction({
  'gas': 500000,
  'gasPrice': w3.toWei(gas_p, 'gwei'),
  'nonce': nonce,
})
signed_txn = w3.eth.account.signTransaction(txn_dict, private_key=wallet_private_key)
result = w3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
```

I was wondering if it was possible to put that 'approve' method into the Solidity contract, but then thought, this would be bad because a malicious contract might execute the `approve` & `transfer` functions within the same block, allowing a token overspend. Is that the right way to think about it? [I could be wrong in my assumption that you cannot approve an ERC-20 token expenditure within a Solidity contract]

It's interesting because, on one hand, I could imagine the token's allowance amount would be modified when a transfer function was called, or not, depending on whether the Solidity contracts are run sequentially in a block, or simultaneously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to call `approve` from a Solidity contract on behalf of a user. You can use it to allow another contract to spend the tokens in the contract itself. The `approve` function looks like this:

```
function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success)
```

As you can see, there is no way to specify the address to `approve` for. It will use `msg.sender`, which in the case of calling it from a contract, would be the address of the contract itself. That means the user has to send a transaction from their own address in order to allow `_spender` (which could be a contract) to send the tokens.

Comment: Thanks. Can you address whether or not my inference about why this function is restricted this way is correct? Specifically, that if 'approve' was accessible within a contract, one could then transfer more than the approved amount in a single contract's execution?

Comment: I think what you are referring to is a [reentrancy attack](https://consensys.github.io/smart-contract-best-practices/known_attacks/#reentrancy). Token contracts themselves should have some kind of protection from these attacks. I think the reason why a smart contract cannot call `approve` on behalf of the user is authorisation: the token contract cannot (with the current specification) verify that the user wants to `approve`. There are some other token standards like ERC-777 that use a different approach for allowance, so that the user won't have to send two transactions.